# is on-premise Sharepoint 2016 REST API possible with oauth?

Tags: rest, api, cors

I have a Sharepoint 2016 server and a python web server. I would like to read data from Sharepoint with my python server. I was able to do this on Office 365 on the cloud but did not find much information on how to do this with on-premise versions.

How do I 'register my app' with the on-premise Sharepoint? Is it possible to read data from the python server?

Comment: Looking back at this few years after the mess has been resolved - I did not find any open source libraries out there and resorted to writing my own requests. For anyone reading through this post: it was not enjoyable. please give up all hope and quit your project before its too late.